# Storing index values in FAST-ESP without modifications

Tags: search, performance, fast-esp

first of all I'm totally new to FAST but I already have a couple of issues I need to solve, so I'm sorry if my questions are very basic =)

Well, the problem is that I have a field in the FAST index which in the source document is something like

```
"ABC   12345"
```

(please note the intentional whitespaces) but when stored in the index is in the form

```
"ABC 123456"
```

(please note that now there is a single space).

If I retrieve all the document values then this specific value is OK (with all the whitespaces), my only problem is with the way the value is stored in the index since I need to retrieve and display it to my user just like it appears in the original document, and I don't want to go to the full document just for this value, I want the value that I already have in the index. I think I need to update one of the FAST XML configuration files but I don't have enough documentation at hand in order to decide where to perform the change, index_profile.xml? in the XMLMapper file?

Comment: I don't know if that's possible. I think the indexer automatically strips all whitespaces and I haven't read or seen any config to change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer by myself. I'm using a XMLMapper for my collection, all I had to do was to add the **ignore-whitespace attribute to the Mapping element** and then set this attribute value to "false". This solved the problem and the raw data now when retrieved from the index contains the expected inner whitespaces.

Thanks.